# Why can't I see parent state from child component event handler?

Tags: reactjs

I have two components: *Meal* and *Ingredient*.  *Ingredient* is always a child of *Meal*.  I pass the function below to each Ingredient as a prop, e.g. `<Ingredient deleteIngFunc={handleDeleteIng} />`.

What the button in Ingredient is clicked, *Ingredient* fires `prop.deleteIngFunc` but when I console.debug the `ingsArrayCopy` from the the function, it is empty!  It shouldn't be empty because the state is obviously there when the page renders (i.e. the ingredients are displayed on the page, so the state is obviously not empty)

Meal.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Ingredient from './Ingredient';

function Meal(props){
    const [ingArray, setIngArray] = useState([]);

    function handleDeleteIng(e){
        let ingsArrayCopy = [...ingArray];
        console.debug(ingsArrayCopy); // empty array??
    }

    async function initIngs(){
        let ings = props.ings.map(
            ing => (
                <Ingredient title={ing.title} id={ing.id} deleteIngFunc={handleDeleteIng} />
            )
        )

        return await setIngArray(prev => ings)
    }

    function updateIngs(newIngObject){
        let oldIngState = [...ingArray];

        let newIng = <Ingredient key={newIngObject.id} id={newIngObject.id} title={newIngObject.title} />

        let newIngState = oldIngState.concat([newIng]);

        setIngArray(prev => newIngState);
    }


    useEffect(
        () => {
            initIngs();
        },
        []
    );

    return (
        <ul>
            {ingArray}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default Meal;
```

Ingredient.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import CancelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Cancel';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';

function Ingredient(props){

    function handleDeletion(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        props.deleteIngFunc(e)
    }

    return (
        <li
            key={props.id}
            className="ingredient-listitem"
        >
            <Typography className="ingredient-text">{props.title}</Typography>

            <IconButton onClick={handleDeletion}>
                <CancelIcon></CancelIcon>
            </IconButton>
        </li>
    )
}

export default Ingredient;
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is  the value of the Meal(props)

Comment: The reason this is happening is because `this` changes based on where the function is called from unless you bind the function first. When the function is called within Ingredient `this` is the Ingredient component and not the Meal component that you expect. This could be fixed by binding the function using .bind(this) or using arrow functions, but I would suggest you update your callback functions to use `useCallback` so that they only get recreated when they need too. React Doc: [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the value of **the state cannot be access inside of a regular function**. It can only be access through the following react hooks `useEffect()` `useCallback()` `useMemo()` and on the `return` statement of your functional component.

For Example:

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState('initial Value')

  function someFunction(){
    // It's not recommended to access the state inside of this function
    // cause the value of the state will always be ('initial Value')
    // even if the state were updated
    console.log(state)
   // Why ?
   // Because regular function like this cannot have dependency array
   // And thus without dependency array function will not know that state has changed
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    // It's good if you access the value of the state here
    // It will be assured it will always have the updated value
    console.log(state)
  },[state]) 


  return (
    // You can also access the value of the state inside return statement        
    <>
    {console.log(state)}
    <SomeComponent props={state}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Additionally:** You can set the state on a regular function but you cannot access or read the state on a regular function

I'd included a codesandbox link for a demonstration that are specific to your problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/accessingstate-03hud?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I made a new function using `useCallback` that does the same thing as `handleDeleteIng` and I passed tht into the child component.  The array is still not being read as I expected.

Comment: @RobbieS Double check it you add the value in the dependency array. You can show me your code if you need to

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-rhodes-f2qwn?file=/src/testdata.js;  It might throw dependency errors; but if you refresh the mini browser, it loads correctly

Comment: I refactored and rewritten your code check it out https://codesandbox.io/s/refactored-react-r3crt?file=/src/Meal.js

Comment: I'm blown away.  Thank you!  I'll read this and learn

Comment: @RobbieS no problem