# react functional components - child calling parents method, can't accsess parents state inside the function

Tags: react-functional-component

I have a parent component and a list of children component that are buttons and onClick it calls a method in parents component. In that method it checks what the parents state is, and does work according to that. The problem is that when the method gets called - all of a sudden the props it gets from his parent is undefiened.
Here is the parent component

```
const PaymentsInfo = (props) => {

const paymentsList = useSelector((state) => state.payments.paymentsForDonor)

const [payments, setPayments] = useState()
const [showMessage, seShowMessage] = useState(

useEffect(() => {
        if (paymentsList.length > 0) {
            const payments = paymentsList.map(payment => {
                
                return <div key={payment.PaymentsID}><TextButton onClick={() => 
               showMessageHandler(payment)}>View Details</TextButton>
                <TransactionInfo
                    PaymentsID={payment.PaymentsID}
                    campaign={payment.CampaignName}
                    subCampaign={subCampaign}
                    organization={payment.OrganizationName}
                    solicitor={payment.SolicitorName}
                     />
              </div>
            })
            setPayments(payments)
        }
    }, [paymentsList])

    const showMessageHandler = (payment) => {
      if(props.wasChanged){
        setShowMessage(payment)
        return;
      }  
    }


    return (
        <Fragment>
        <div>
            {payments}
        </div>
        {showMessage && <ChangesMessageBox />}
        </Fragment>
    )
```

the method - showMessageHandler gets called, but the props.wasChanged is undefined.
If I check the props.wasChanged the last time it rendered before this function was called it was true, and in the function its undefined

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this question: [Why can't I see parent state from child component event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64112072/why-cant-i-see-parent-state-from-child-component-event-handler).
I added a state in the parent component that gets updated when the child component calls the parents method, and a useEffect that gets called when that state updates that does the work the method was supposed to do

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).